# Is the word »zuordenbar« being used?

Tags: word-usage

The word “assignable” is translated to the German »zuordenbar«, according to several dictionaries. I have never heard this word and it sounds wrong to me. Is it being used?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, *[zuordenbar](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zuordenbar)* is a valid word. And yes, it is being used. But it’s one of the rarer specimens, compared to similar structures like

- *(kann) zugeordnet werden* or
- *zuordnen*

See [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zuordenbar%2Czugeordnet%20werden%2Czuordnen&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Czuordenbar%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czugeordnet%20werden%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Czuordnen%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 6):

It's a perfectly valid word, but watch the context. For example, if you were talking about a variable in a programming language, then I'd translate "assignable" as "zu**weis**bar", not "zu**orden**bar".

Comment: Indeed! 'zuordnen' means something like 'to map' (things that belong together) not like 'to assign' ('zuweisen') for arbitrary grouping..

Answer (score 2):

It's probably just as common as *assignable* ... that said, there's nothing wrong with it. [Duden has it](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zuordenbar), so that should settle it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds very strange to me (German native speaker), I've never heard it before and I would think it's a spelling mistake.
I would use *zuordbar* (without *en*) instead.

It's derived from *zuordnen*, which means *to assign* or *to map* or *to pair*, or something like that. As in "Assign each of these cities to their respective states".

As another_wald has pointed out, in a programming language, or when you talk about assigning tasks, you would probably use *zuweisbar*" instead, which makes clear that a new assignment is being made ("At his first day at work, he was assigned the most boring task"), as opposed to just putting things together, like cities and states. But *zuordbar* can be used for that as well, whereas *zuweisen* always creates a new assignment.

Comment: I feel the same, I've never heared `zuordenbar`, but `zuordbar` sounds familiar.

Comment: I feel the opposite, never heard `zuordbar`. May be a regional difference?

Comment: Zuordbar would be the correct derivation from `*zuorden` if it existed.

Comment: As a software developer in Austria, I heard this word several times (but didn't hear `zuordbar`).