# Wieso Rechen- statt Rechnen-? (Z.B bei „Rechenzentrum“)

Tags: etymology

Es ist mir (zu spät) aufgefallen, dass man *Rechenzentrum* und nicht „Rech**ne**nzentrum“ den Ort nennt, der Maschinen hat (salopp ausgedrückt), die *rechnen*.  Dabei ist *Rechen* nur ein Werkzeug in der Gärtnerei o.ä.

Wie kam *Rechen* dazu, die Fähigkeiten zu rechnen darzustellen. Ist eine phonetische Ähnlichkeit dafür zuständig?

Comment: Das Wort ist ein wenig unglücklich, da ein "Rechen" (etwas anders ausgesprochen) auch [ein Gartengerät](https://images.app.goo.gl/T2LppwB1kKrdfp5NA)  sein kann. Ein Rechenzentrum könnte also auch ein Geschäft sein, das sich auf den Verkauf von Rechen spezialisiert hat ;-)

Comment: @user1934428 ...genauso wie ein Sitzpinkler einer sein könnte, der immer auf den Sitz pinkelt... (Zusammensetzungen sind oft mehrdeutig)

Comment: @tofro: Wie wahr! Man denke nur an die kannibalistischen Speisen "Jägerbraten" und "Kinderschnitzel"!

Comment: Ich habe den Verdacht, dass *zuordenbar* - siehe  diese [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24783/1696) - auf einer ähnlichen Bildung beruht.

Answer (score 7):

Bei Komposita mit verbalem Erstglied steht regelmäßig der Verbstamm: *Bohrmaschine, Greifarm, Leuchtfeuer, Schmierblatt, Sprengkopf, Stolperfalle, Tropfstein, Zitteraal*.

Ich würde *rechen-* als (orthographische) Stammvariante von *rechn-* auffassen: wenn der Laut *n* als Silbengipfel dient, schreibt man *en*, sonst *n*. Im verbalen Paradigma dient *n* nie als Silbengipfel, sondern als Anlaut. Der Silbengipfel wird von der Endung gestellt: *rech.ne, rech.net, rech.nen* etc. Nur in Komposition und Derivation erscheint *rechen-* als Stammvariante mit silbischem *n*: *Rechenzentrum, rechenbar* [ʁɛxn̩-].

Diachron gab es auch *rechenen* und *rechen* ([Lexer](https://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/Lexer?lemid=R00384)), aber ich glaube nicht, dass das hier eine Rolle spielt. Als Erstglied von Komposita ist *rechen-* schon lange vor *Rechenzentrum* etabliert: *Rechenmeister, Rechenpfennig, Rechenstab, Rechentafel*.

Dass der Nasal in eine neue Silbe rückt, ist eine Folge der [Sonoritätshierarchie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonorit%C3%A4tshierarchie). Im verbalen Paradigma dient der Nasal des Stammes dann, wie schon gesagt, als Anlaut der Silbe, während das für Liquide oder Nasale, die nicht Teil des Stammes sind, nicht gilt; sie dienen als Silbengipfel: *segelt* [zeːgl̩t], *lachend* [laxn̩t].

Weitere Beispiele: *zeichnen, zeichenbar; trocknen, trockenbar; zuordnen, zuordenbar; atmen, atembar*. Marginal auch *beregnen, beregenbar; enteignen, enteigenbar; einebnen, einebenbar; segnen, segenbar*. Aber mit Wegfall des Nasals *leugnen, leugbar*.

Comment: Ja, und die Form mit Infinitivendung "rechn-en" kann in Komposita normalerweise aus generellen grammatischen Gründen nicht auftreten.

Comment: Ich habe jetzt mutiger formuliert.

Comment: Schöne Erklärung! Gibt es noch andere Beispiele, in denen ein im Infinitiv verschwundenes e wieder auftaucht? Mir fällt ad hoc für ein verschwindendes e nur _Dresdner Straße_ ein, aber das kommt nirgends wieder zum Vorschein.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach Das *e* "fehlt" im ganzen verbalen Paradigma: *rechn‑e, ‑en, ‑et, ‑ete, ‑end*; *n* bildet dann den Anlaut der Endungssilbe. Nur, wenn es keine Endung gibt, tritt *rechen-* auf. Anders bei *segel‑e, ‑n, ‑t, ‑te, ‑nd*: hier bildet *l* immer den Gipfel einer eigenen Silbe. Bei *segele* > *segle* liegt dann optionale Synkope vor.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach *Zeichenstift*, *Zeichentrickfilm*

Comment: Im Mittealter war **[Rechenmeister](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rechenmeister)** ein bekannter Beruf.  Im deutschsprachigen Raum ist [Adam Ries(e)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Ries) bis heute bekannt.